# Hint on solving the second order differential equation $(x^2-3x)y''+xy'-(x+3)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I want to solve this differential equation:

$$(x^2-3x)y''+xy'-(x+3)y=0$$

The original question is as follows:

$0<x<3$ is the largest interval in which the solution of

$(x^2-3x)y''+xy'-(x+3)y=0$, $y(1)=2$,

$y'(1)=1$ is certain to exist?

So I tried by taking y=uv as complete solution. Then I tried to apply Normal form method and got $u=1/\sqrt{x-3}$. So by putting value of P and  Q in normal form formula I got, $v''+[4x^2+x-36/4x(x-3)^2]v=0$. How should I solve further? Is there a 'nicer' way to solve.

Comment: I don't think you need to solve the equation. You only need to prove that the solution exists on that interval, and cannot be continued beyond it. Hint: at $0$ and $3$ the coefficient $x^2 - 3x$ vanishes.

Comment: Can you explain it further? Thanks for answering! So is it because $u$  becomes imaginary between 0 and 3?

Comment: Also how do I show that the solution cannot be continued beyond it?

Comment: The standard form of a second order linear differential equation is

$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=g(x)$$
$$y(x_0)=y_0,\quad y'(x_0)=y'_0$$

Rewrite your equation in standard form

$$y''+\frac{x}{x^2-3x}y'-\frac{x+3}{x^2-3x}y=0$$
$$y(1)=2,\quad y'(1)=1$$

By the [existence and uniqueness theorem](http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/204/constantcoeff/uniquenessExistence.htm) for second order differential equations, $p(x),q(x),$ and $g(x)$ are all continuous except at $x=0$ and $x=3$. Therefore there is a unique solution on the interval $[0,3]$.

Comment: @user58697 Did you read “I want to solve… “ Statement ?.

Comment: @Axion004 Thank you so much. It helped in answering 
my question.  Although I'd still like to solve the differential equation! Thanks again

Comment: @FelixMarin Of course. That's why I didn't _answer_, but tried to steer OP into the right direction. Attempting to _solve_ the equation is an exercise in futility, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think that a power series solution should work (similar to one shown inside [these solutions](https://www.ualberta.ca/~csproat/Homework/MATH%20334/Assignment%20Solutions/Assignment%206%20Solutions.pdf).)

Comment: Thank you@Axion004